# Remove rows that are in another dataframe when there are duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to remove rows that are in one dataframe, if another dataframe has the same rows. However, I don't want to remove all the rows, only the number of rows that are in the other dataframe. Refer to this example:

`df1`

```
   col1  col2
0     1    10
1     1    10
2     2    11
3     3    12
4     1    10
```

`df2`

```
   col1  col2
0     1    10
1     2    11
2     1    10
3     3    12
4     3    12
```

Desired output:

`df1`

```
   col1  col2
      1    10
```

Because `df1` has 3 rows of 1,10 while `df2` has 2 rows of 1,10 so you remove 2 from each, leaving 1 for `df1`. If there were 4 rows in `df1`, I would want two rows of 1,10 in `df1` as a result. Same with `df2` below:

`df2`

```
   col1  col2
      3    12
```

My attempt:

I was maybe thinking of counting how many duplicates are in each of the dataframe and creating new `df1` and `df2` by subtracting the `dupe_count`  but wondering if there's a more efficient way.

```
df1g=df1.groupby(df1.columns.tolist(),as_index=False).size().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'dupe_count'})
df2g=df2.groupby(df2.columns.tolist(),as_index=False).size().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'dupe_count'})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a non-trivial problem, but `merge` is your friend:

```
a, b = (df.assign(count=df.groupby([*df]).cumcount()) for df in (df1, df2))    
df1[a.merge(b, on=[*a], indicator=True, how='left').eval('_merge == "left_only"')]

   col1  col2
4     1    10
```

---

The idea here is to add a `cumcount` column to de-duplicate the columns (assign a unique identifier to each). We can then see which rows aren't matched on a subsequent merge.

```
a
   col1  col2  count
0     1    10      0
1     1    10      1
2     2    11      0
3     3    12      0
4     1    10      2

b
   col1  col2  count
0     1    10      0
1     2    11      0
2     1    10      1
3     3    12      0
4     3    12      1

a.merge(b, on=[*a], indicator=True, how='left')
   col1  col2  count     _merge
0     1    10      0       both
1     1    10      1       both
2     2    11      0       both
3     3    12      0       both
4     1    10      2  left_only

_.eval('_merge == "left_only"')
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
dtype: bool
```

---

If you need to get unmatched rows from both `df1` and `df2`, use an outer merge:

```
out = a.merge(b, on=[*a], indicator=True, how='outer')
df1_filter = (
    out.query('_merge == "left_only"').drop(['count','_merge'], axis=1))
df2_filter = (
    out.query('_merge == "right_only"').drop(['count','_merge'], axis=1))

df1_filter
   col1  col2
4     1    10

df2_filter
   col1  col2
5     3    12
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach which use `repeat`:

```
# count of the rows
c1 = df1.groupby(['col1', 'col2']).size()
c2 = df2.groupby(['col1', 'col2']).size()

# repeat the rows by values
(c1.repeat((c1-c2).clip(0))
   .reset_index()
   .drop(0, axis=1)
)
#   col1    col2
# 0 1   10

(c2.repeat((c2-c1).clip(0))
   .reset_index()
   .drop(0, axis=1)
)
#   col1    col2
# 0 3   12
```

Comment: Only downside to this compared to other answer is error when there are `NaN` in some columns: groupby().Size() giving 'Value Error : Length of passed values is x, index implies 0' [issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/23050). Maybe it will get fixed in 0.25+.